# htaccess mod_rewrite not passing get variables on live server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have created a mod_rewrite rule for my blog which works final on my local server but when I upload to my live server it's not passing the $_GET variables. I've managed to break the problem down into it's simplest form. Here's the mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^test/([^/\.]+)$ test.php?var=$1 [QSA]
```

The file test.php is in the root of the site and simply has the following code in it:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_GET);
echo '</pre>';
```

So when I go to mysite.co.uk/test/hello on my local server I'm getting

```
Array
(
    [var] => hello
)
```

As I would expect. But when I try on my live site I'm still getting redirected to my test.php page, just without the $_GET variables:

```
Array
(
)
```

Does anybody have any ideas what could cause this? I've ran into a plethora of weird occurrences whilst trying to get this to work and any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: I have. It's in my public_html folder and nowhere else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to [`Content Negotiation` turned on my `MultVIews`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html) Options in Apache.

Place this line on top of your `.htaccess` to turn off `MultiViews`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
```

Comment: Thanks buddy you're a lifesaver - I was tearing my hair out over that one!